# AC current measurement using shunt resistor

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, ac, adc, shunt

I need to measure AC RMS current using shunt resistor. AC current range is 0-8A RMS. Shunt resistor chosen is 100 mohm. which gives me max 8*1.414*10=1.13 Volt that i will use to feed an opamp to further amplify it to around max 3V with proper gain setting. and that will go to my micro controller ADC ( 0 to 3V only). Since in my circuit only positive supply is there so I used single supply op amp, (Negative half cycle will be chopped by opamp, i think). below is the ruff circuit.

which circuit out of below two looks ok to start.

[image]

Comment: it depends what you mean by your ground symbol. CKT1 looks rather hazardous, earthing the live terminal.

Comment: What is the AC voltage? If it is mains voltage, you need to rethink your entire approach. I don't think you will want to use a shunt. Probably you should use a current transformer or a Hall effect current sensor (such as ACS712) with an isolation rating. CKT2, in particular, directly connects full load voltage across your bottom 22pF capacitor. You certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: If you must use a shunt, it should be on the N side. You can capacitively couple the shunt voltage to your amplifier. But this seems like a potential safety hazard, depending on what you are trying to do. It might help to provide more background on what you are doing.

Comment: its 230V AC line voltage, need low cost solution , thats why i used shunt resistor, CT is bit costly here,  also i can not use shunt on low side since load is outside the unit.

Comment: First rule of measuring RMS current is don't screw it up by rectifying it. Can you handle 6 watts being dissipated by the resistor?

Comment: thanks @Andy aka to point out this, yes i can lower the shunt resistor value , that can be further amplify by op-amp gain, only problem is AC has negative cycle also , but i do not have negative supply for op-amp, so i hope op-amp will chopped negative half cycle. ( in firmware that can be manipulated).  or is there is any low cost method to measure AC current.

Comment: Isolation is going to be a big problem. The way you have drawn it, your entire circuit is hazardous to the touch and needs to be isolated. Just testing and debugging it is going to be extremely difficult.

Comment: I believe there will be some method to sense AC current via shunt and feed to ADC. (non isolated method for very lost solution)

Comment: I created a shunt of 12 milliohms using 3 feet of 16 AWG solid wire, if I recall correctly. I put it on the neutral side of a duplex (USA) outlet, breaking off the ear and bridging it with the shunt wire. I put it all in a metal outlet box with a 3-wire cord. Using a multimeter across the white terminals, it read 0.1 volts for 1000W (which is 8.3 Amps at 120 Volts). Still, 3 feet of wire folded up (not coiled) is fairly big. And it would dissipate about 1 Watt of heat. A shunt might not be the best solution, but then what is?

Comment: @mkeith To have the shunt in the wire N does not make it safe - not even if you can quarantee the polarity to stay. Think about a broken N-wire. You will get the mains through the load.

Comment: @user287001, putting the shunt on the neutral would be safer in practice because both sides of shunt would PROBABLY not shock you under normal conditions if you touched them. You would still have to design for total isolation. Would not change the design requirements.

Answer (score 2):

First: Your uC will get galvanic contact to AC mains. It will be quite a stunning effect to notice it suddenly during the use, if not taken into the account from the beginning.

The whole uC system must be safely insulated without any reachable circuitry. This is a challenge until it is battery powered and no external devices are connected otherwise than wirelessly.

If you had placed the sense resistor to N wire and secure the system to stay like that, the insulation requirements would be lesser. Unfortunately you have no way to quarantee the polarity to stay and the N-wire to be unbreakable. Thus in practice no insulation relief would be available.

**At least consider to have a current transformer** or a current clamp (=transformer or Hall-effect) to break the galvanic contact to AC mains. It shoud be no problem with 50...60 Hz and current this big. It solves the insulation problem instantly, because there's no galvanic contact. If the current transformer or clamp costs too much, think about an optocoupler in linear mode or a homebrew current transformer.

Second: Your differential amplifier has only 3 resistors, 4 is required if you want the result to be the current.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to connect to a main, I would use an opto-isolator solution, right out of the gate. I've done this with a large battery bank to measure voltage and +- current. I did not want to create a ground loop with equipment and the bank. The MSP430f2013 has a 16 bit DS ADC, lot of bits. Keep your shunt down in the millivolt range and the ADC will measure negative to Vdd very well.

It is so low power that you can supply it from a simple diode/capacitor supply from the other side of the main. At that, TI has a line of MSP430s specifically meant for this kind of work, and with 24 bits. [Sub-metering made easy](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slay020/slay020.pdf). What I like about the 2013 is, it comes in a dip for cheap and easy prototyping, and it is cheap. Probably cheaper than using op amps to get to some other micro without isolation. In my case I used the UART to pump a stream of data through the opto-isolator.